# Question on sheaves axioms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $U,V$ two open subset of a topological space $X$ with non-empty intersection. Let $F$ be a sheaf of commutative rings on $X$ and say $\rho$ are its transition maps

> Let $f\in F(U\cup V)$. Is it true that $\rho^U_{U\cap V}(f)=\rho^V_{U\cap V}(f)$ ?? It should follow directly from the sheaves axioms but actually I can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean
$$\rho_{U\cap V}^U(\rho_U^{U\cup V}(f))
=\rho_{U\cap V}^V(\rho_V^{U\cup V}(f))?$$
By the sheaf axioms, both sides are $\rho_{U\cap V}^{U\cup V}(f)$.

Comment: oh sorry you are right I just write badly. Then it was obvious

Comment: Thus follows from this that we can see an element of $F(U\cup V)$ as a pair $(s,t)$ where $s\in F(U),t\in F(V)$ and $s,t$ agree on the intersection? Because my question arises from this other issue

Comment: @Blacksmith The four groups involved form a pull-back square.

Comment: But this issue has nothing to do with the sheaf axioms, and is true for any presheaf.